# Passing Values to DB and Viewing it w/ 100% JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, database, forms, html

How do JavaScript-heavy web applications route freshly-entered data to a database, and then display it to the client, only using JavaScript/HTML?

Say Acme Social Network user types profile information into a HTML form and clicks 'submit':

- How would you save that user's profile data to a database?
- How would you then display that user's profile data on the profile page?

Can it all be done with JS/HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *could* use [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) as the backend, or use [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) with a more traditional DB (or CouchDB), but most people still use a LAMP stack for the backend (often with a framework such as [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/), [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)).

Answer (score 2):

There's always a server-side programming language that interacts directly with the database and generates pages with that data. On a javascript heavy page, there might be an AJAX call that sends the data to a server-side script to store in the database. Information can be pulled from the server with AJAX requests as well. But there's always server-side code that the front end is interacting with.